# why item group getting key instead of value?

Tags: java, json, minecraft, minecraft-forge

The item group name appearing as "itemGroup.dragon quest" instead of "dragon quest"

My little project is on [github](https://github.com/fgsoftware1/dragon_quest-forge), and I made an issue with some screen [here](https://github.com/fgsoftware1/dragon_quest-forge/issues/1)

Comment: Yes, so if it's already reported to the author, it's fine ? Can you explain more where are you stuck etc ? And why post on SO if there already has an issue the github of the project ?

Comment: @Elikill58 the project is mine and probably no one will find it

Comment: Oh ok. I suggest you to read [ask] and to try to make a [mre], (or at least reduce the code than just give repo link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found where thr problem comes from. [here](https://github.com/fgsoftware1/dragon_quest-forge/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fgsoftwarestudio/dragonquest/DragonquestItemGroup.java#L11) you are putting the key "dragon quest". I think it's used everywhere to get the name.

If you remove the space (and so, have `super("dragonquest");`), you will see the translation [here](https://github.com/fgsoftware1/dragon_quest-forge/blob/master/src/main/resources/assets/dragonquest/lang/en_us.json#L3) : "Tutorial Item Group".

And so, you should change the lang file to change the name showed in the inventory name.